# How do I keep the format I inputed the text in when i display it?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have a database with a table for CD releases. One column is a text column called description where you can put in a long description along with a tracklist and so on. The problem is that when I display it there is no new lines (unless you use 
) and Swedish charachters like ÅÄÖ will be displayed incorrectly. The biggest problem by far is that I have to use 
 to get a new line but it would be nice to fix the ÅÄÖ problem too since some bands have Swedish names and so on.

I just display it like this (simplified):

```
$ID = $_REQUEST['catnum'];
    $query = "SELECT catnum, band, title, format, releasedate, description, cover FROM releases WHERE catnum='$ID'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['description'];
```

Thsis what it looks like: http://cmenbazinga.se/unexploded/release.php?catnum=UER001

Comment: May I recommend [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `meta` tag states that the text is in UTF-8, but it's actually Latin-1. Transcode your text from Latin-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: Exactly where do I do that? And how?

Comment: You can either do it in PHP right before echoing it, or you can convert the MySQL column to UTF-8.

Comment: I recommend having UTF-8 in MySQL since that will solve *all* encoding problems, present and future, but then the *entire* data path must be made UTF-8-clean. It can be a large task, but the benefits can be worth it.

Comment: Ok, could you please point me in the right direction for how to do this? Also will it solve the problems with new line's not appearing when you echo the text?

Comment: Newlines are because you forgot to use [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+convert+utf-8

Comment: I had no idea I had to to that :) I'm not good at PHP at all, only reason I get by is cuz I've worked with VB.net, C# so I have the logic but not the syntax :)

Comment: Thank you so much you definitely deserve the acceptet answer on this one :)